# How can I export a Physics Simulation from Blender for Spark AR?

Tags: augmented-reality, blender, fbx, spark-ar-studio

Alright, I've been trying to achieve this for the past two days but I'm at my wits end. The following animation was made using the cloth physics in blender 2.82:

[image: The .mdd applied to the SparkAR FaceMesh]

My goal is to import it in Spark AR in order to map the face-tracker texture on it. Unfortunately, no matter how I export it from Blender, I'm unable to trigger the animation in SparkAR. As a reference, here's another effect which probably uses something similar:

[image: A filter published on Instagram which uses a similar mechanic]

**Here's my workflow:**

**Step 1**
Animating the mesh in Blender using the cloth physics simulation.

**Step 2**
Exporting a .mdd (Lightwave Point Cache) in order to extract the animation. Since Spark AR doesn't feature cloth animations, I found this way to get rid of the physics but keep the animation.

**Step 3**
Make a new file in Blender > import the SparkAR FaceMesh > Apply the .mdd Animation > Bake the Animation > Export .FBX file

**Step 4**
Open Spark AR > Import .FBX file into Spark AR > Add playback controller > assign it to the object

**Step 5** Confusion: Nothing moves. Instead, I get a deformation map for every frame:

[image: confusion]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Why does this have javascript and c# tags?

Comment: Because SparkAR supports javascript scripts and I thought it might be possible to solve the issue via a script. C# is my bad though, I removed it. Thanks!